# Object in cycles render doesn’t render properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Everything else in the project is rendering perfectly fine other than the bolt on the right. In the 3D viewport it seems to be rendering perfectly fine but when I do the final render it out it doesn’t seem to reflect any light. The only light source in the image is the box that has an emission material, but even when I add other lights around it the bolt doesn’t seem to reflect light. Is the light acting normally and I think it’s being weird for no reason? And does anyone know why this could be happening if it isn’t normal?[image]

I wasn't able to attach the .blend file because it was too large, i' uploaded it onto google drive instead:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ebyqKGy8z6mZqjYhVsPwJ3xJxXvFUPn_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Normals may be inverted. Can you add the viewport render screenshot? Since the viewport render looks ok, check for hidden objects or modifiers, and check that modifiers with alternate viewport and render settings (such as subdivision surface) are not causing this.

Comment: or you could provide your blend file so we can also check your material settings, your lights...etc.